# 2 slides Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

my slides is working properly but instead of working at the same time    the sidebar slides will wait before the section slides is don't.

```
First Slide
<section id="section">
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
<img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide1.JPEG" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide2.JPEG" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide3.JPEG" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="slides/slide4.JPEG" style="width:100%">
</div>
Script ====

<script>


var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
}
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: I used the same code for my second slide